# Initialization of selectpicker fail when dependent on other value in laravel livewire

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-livewire, bootstrap-selectpicker

Used all the possible solution to make it work

**PROBLEM**

When enabling toggle button I want to show two div's one for normal select tag and second for selectpicker but it always fails. But selectpicker doesn't render correctly.
Any help would be appreciated.

**NOTE**
Selectpicker CSS and JS is already initialized in laravel blade file.

**CODE**

```
<div>
    <x-alert>
    </x-alert>
    <form class="kt-form" wire:submit.prevent="updateChanges">
        <div class="kt-portlet kt-portlet--mobile">
            <div class="kt-portlet__body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="hidden" wire:model="user_id">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-3 col-form-label">Enable Preference</label>
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <span class="kt-switch">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="hidden" wire:model="is_prefered" value="0">
                                    <input type="checkbox" wire:model="is_prefered" value="1" >
                                    <span></span>
                                </label>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @error('is_prefered') <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>@enderror
                </div>
                @if($is_prefered=="1")
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Type</label>
                    <select wire:model="type" class="form-control">
                        <option value="selected">Select Preference Type</option>
                        <option value="user">User</option>
                        <option value="keyword">Keyword</option>
                    </select>                    
                    @error('type') <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>@enderror
                </div>
                @endif
                @if($is_prefered=="1")
                <div class="form-group">
                    @if($type == 'user')
                    <label for="">Value</label>
                        <select class="form-control kt-selectpicker" multiple >
                            <option value="" disabled>Select User</option>
                            @foreach($users as $user)
                                <option value="{{ $user->id }}" @if($type_value)@if(in_array($user->id,$type_value)) selected @endif @endif>{{ $user->name }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    @elseif($type == 'keyword')
                    <label for="">Value</label>
                        <input type="text" wire:model="type_value" class="form-control">
                    @endif
                    @error('type') <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>@enderror
                </div>
                @endif
            </div>
            <div class="kt-portlet__foot">
                <div class="kt-form__actions">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-secondary">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the option in the foreach section...

id}}" {{#if $type_value}} {{#if in_array($user->id,$type_value}} selected {{/if}} {{/if}}>{{$user->name}}

Comment: It doesn't matter what I do with selected values. The problem is when I update the value on change selectpicker doesn't render